# Color getting overlapped in the indicator MQL5

Tags: mql5, metatrader5, mt

I am trying to paint the portions of the graph with Bollinger Bands. But while coloring the graph bands some portions are appearing to be colored with 2 colors or overlapped with colors,

See the following image:

[image: My image]

See the portion marked with yellow rectangle. What can I do to avoid such overlapping for the colors?

How I can avoid this overlap? As it is making the visibility unable to understand what colors present at the moment. This [documentation](https://www.mql5.com/go?link=https://www.mql5.com/en/articles/1341) is not helpful right now.

I am just using  the following :

```
//--- plot Label1
#property indicator_label1  "UpTrend"
#property indicator_type1   DRAW_FILLING
#property indicator_color1  DarkGreen//C'10,10,70'
#property indicator_style1  STYLE_SOLID 
#property indicator_width1  1
//--- plot Label2
#property indicator_label2  "DnTrend"
#property indicator_type2   DRAW_FILLING
#property indicator_color2  C'70,10,10'
#property indicator_style2  STYLE_SOLID
#property indicator_width2  1
//--- plot Label3
#property indicator_label3  "Flat"
#property indicator_type3   DRAW_FILLING
#property indicator_color3  Aqua//C'50,50,50'
#property indicator_style3  STYLE_SOLID
#property indicator_width3  1
```

Answer (score 0):

> **How I can avoid this overlap?**

Well, actually you can't.

There is no such tool inside the MetaTrader Terminal native GUI-engine to do so.

Yet, one may build one's own, remote GUI-engine, where any such tooling gets available ( and just communicate with the MT4/5 Terminal MQL4/5-code ).
[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Can you please explain or give an example how to achieve what you have suggested? I am having no idea of what you mean. Please let me know.